# SSL certification authorization in OWIN Katana

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-web-api2, katana, owin-middleware

I have a requirement to develop a lightweight Web API, which shall get the request message from client, add it to the queue(MSMQ / DB) and reply with status code and the API should be developed in .net technology.

- Number of requests that the API shall serve is approximately 400 requests per second with out any single request lost.
- Certificate based authentication(over HTTPS) capability to be provided.

I have two options

1. Web API and deployed in IIS
2. Web API with OWIN Katana hosted in windows service

My question is which one of the above shall be a better option for the requirement?
If I go with OWIN Katana, then how feasible/complex to implement certification authentication(TLS mutual certificate validation)?